# Basic central limit theorem question

Tags: probability, solution-verification, problem-solving, central-limit-theorem

A company sells lottery scratch cards for £1 each. 1% of cards win £50, 20% win £2 and the rest win nothing. Estimate how many cards the company needs to sell to be 99% sure of making an overall profit.

I worked out that the expected gain for the company from a single card sold is 0.1 and the variance is 24.99. Plugging these into CLT I got that the number of cards needs to be bigger than 1,352,376 - does this seem right? Just seems like a big number!

Comment: Looks like you have a decimal point issue, I get 13523.76 (or maybe I have a decimal point issue). I am using $Q(2.3263)=.01$. I agree with your mean and variance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I have the same as you now :)